# How would I go about reading the log to check if a command is finished executing before running another command?

Tags: bash

This is a bash script I wrote that automatically trims all the worlds for a minecraft server at an interval specified in crontab. It will execute the "/wb $WORLD trim" command and the "/wb trim confirm" command on each world, one by one, where $WORLD is the world that it is currently working on. By loading each world from a list of files into a for loop, it will trim each world sequentially. Right now, since world trimming can take a varying amount of time, I'm unsure how to tell it to not stop if it isn't done yet, since only 30 seconds are allocated to each world. I figure that reading the log file to get the status of the command might work, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing so. I figure something like "grep" and "awk" might do the job, but I'm not sure whether that will work, as this seems to be a pretty complicated roadblock. Any ideas? I have the part of a log file that it prints while trimming a world posted [here](http://pastebin.com/M6Y314SS) on pastebin. Also, is there anything besides that I could do to improve this script? I've only been writing code for a couple of months, and not that often at that, so I'm new to programming/scripting in general.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Title: World Border Trim Automator
# Author: Jonathan Bondhus

######### CONFIG STARTS HERE #########

# Location of the init script
INIT_SCRIPT="/etc/init.d/minecraft"

# Name to use for the screen instance
SCREEN="minecraft"

# User that should run the server
USERNAME="minecraft"

# Path to minecraft server directory 
MCPATH="/home/${USERNAME}/minecraft"

# Where the worlds are located on the disk
WORLDSTORAGE="${MCPATH}/worlds"

######### CONFIG ENDS HERE #########

## Start of script, don't edit anything below this line unless you know what you are doing

as_user() {
    if [ $ME == $USERNAME ] ; then
        bash -c "$1"
    else
        su $USERNAME -s /bin/bash -c "$1"
    fi
}

my_trim() {
    a=1
    for NAME in $(ls $WORLDSTORAGE)
    do
        if [ -d $WORLDSTORAGE/$NAME ]
        then
            WORLDNAME[$a]=$NAME
            a=$a+1
            # Run the /wb trim command
            echo "Running /wb $NAME trim..."
            as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"wb $NAME trim\"\015'"
            sleep 2     # Wait 2 seconds
            clear
            echo "Running /wb trim confirm..."
            as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"wb trim confirm\"\015'"
            sleep 1
            clear
            echo "Waiting 30 seconds for trim to complete..."
            sleep 30    # Wait 30 seconds
        fi
    done
}

my_is_running(){
    # Checks for the minecraft servers screen session
    # returns true if it exists.
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "$SCREEN $INVOCATION" > /dev/null
    then
        return 0
    fi
    return 1
}

my_main(){
    ME=`whoami`     # Sets $ME to equal the current user's username
    my_is_running
    if my_is_running
        then
            my_trim
        else
            echo "Server is not running... Starting..."
            my_as_user "$INIT_SCRIPT start"
            wait 100
    fi
}

my_as_user() {
    if [ $me == $username ] ; then
        bash -c "$1"
    else
        su $USERNAME -s /bin/bash -c "$1"
    fi
}

my_main
exit 0
```

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) and don't do `for var in $(ls)` - all you need is a glob. Use `((a++))` for incrementing the variable. The way you're doing it, `a` is an ever-growing string of `1+1+1+1...+1` (which does get mathematically evaluated in the subscript of the array).

Comment: You don't need `bash -c "$1"` - you can just use `$1` directly (on a line by itself).

Comment: The pastebin link is broken; example log can be found at [World Border Trim Script for Minecraft Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922982/world-border-trim-script-for-minecraft-server).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're running 'stuff' inside 'screen'?

If you removed it, 'stuff' will execute synchronously, and return after the command completes.

```
my_trim() {
    a=1
    for NAME in $(ls $WORLDSTORAGE)
    do
        if [ -d $WORLDSTORAGE/$NAME ]
        then
            WORLDNAME[$a]=$NAME
            a=$a+1
            # Run the /wb trim command
            echo "Running /wb $NAME trim..."
            as_user "stuff \"wb $NAME trim\"\015" # will block here until stuff returns
            #sleep 2     # no reason this any more
            clear
            echo "Running /wb trim confirm..."
            as_user "stuff \"wb trim confirm\"\015"
            #sleep 1
            clear
            echo "Done"
            #sleep 30
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: `stuff` is a _screen_ command; as such, it cannot be run outside of _screen_.

Answer (score 0):

In the following it is assumed that the variable `MCLOGFILE` is set to the log file name.

```
my_trim() {
    cd $WORLDSTORAGE
    for NAME in *
    do
        if [ -d $NAME ]
        then
            # Run the /wb trim command
            echo "Running /wb $NAME trim..."
            as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"wb $NAME trim\"\015'"
            sleep 2     # Wait 2 seconds
            clear
            echo "Running /wb trim confirm..."
    kill `((tail -f $MCLOGFILE -n0& echo $! >&3
            as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"wb trim confirm\"\015'"
            sleep 1
            clear >&2
            echo "Waiting for trim to complete..." >&2
           )|grep -q 'task successfully completed!'
          ) 3>&1|head -1
         `
        fi
    done
}
```

The `kill` stuff is there because otherwise `tail` would continue to run in the background until a line after the one with `task successfully completed!` were written to the log file.