# World Border Trim Script for Minecraft Server

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script that trims the worlds of a minecraft server every day at 5 AM. So far, it runs the command /wb $NAME trim, where $NAME is the name of the world, and then it runs the command /wb trim confirm, to initialize the trimming process.

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/trim
# Title: World Border Trim Automator
# Author: Jonathan Bondhus

######### CONFIG STARTS HERE #########

# Location of the init script
INIT_SCRIPT="/etc/init.d/minecraft"

# Name to use for the screen instance
SCREEN="minecraft"

# User that should run the server
USERNAME="minecraft"

# Path to minecraft server directory 
MCPATH="/home/${USERNAME}/minecraft"

# Where the worlds are located on the disk
WORLDSTORAGE="${MCPATH}/worlds"

######### CONFIG ENDS HERE #########

## Start of script, don't edit anything below this line unless you know what you are doing

as_user() {
    if [ $ME == $USERNAME ] ; then
        bash -c "$1"
    else
        su $USERNAME -s /bin/bash -c "$1"
    fi
}

my_trim() {
    a=1
    for NAME in $(ls $WORLDSTORAGE)
    do
        if [ -d $WORLDSTORAGE/$NAME ]
        then
            WORLDNAME[$a]=$NAME
            a=$a+1
            # Run the /wb trim command
            echo "Running /wb $NAME trim..."
            as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"wb $NAME trim\"\015'"
            sleep 2     # Wait 2 seconds
            echo "Running /wb trim confirm..."
            as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"wb trim confirm\"\015'"
            echo "Waiting 10 minutes for trim to complete"
            sleep 600   # Wait 10 minutes (600 seconds)
        fi
    done
}

my_is_running(){
    # Checks for the minecraft servers screen session
    # returns true if it exists.
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "$SCREEN $INVOCATION" > /dev/null
    then
        return 0
    fi
    return 1
}

my_main(){
    ME=`whoami`     # Sets $ME to equal the current user's username
    my_is_running
    if my_is_running
        then
            my_trim
        else
            echo "Server is not running... Starting..."
            my_as_user "$INIT_SCRIPT start"
            wait 100
    fi
}

my_as_user() {
    if [ $me == $username ] ; then
        bash -c "$1"
    else
        su $USERNAME -s /bin/bash -c "$1"
    fi
}

my_main
exit 0
```

There is one problem. If it tries running it again while the trimming process is still taking place, then the server will ignore that request, and the script will keep running as if nothing has gone wrong. What I want it to do, is check the log until it finds that the trim is completed. The log file throughout a trim will look something like this:

```
2012-08-12 03:58:08 [INFO] World trimming task is ready for world "world", trimming the map past 208 blocks beyond the border (default 208), and the task will try to process up to 5000 chunks per second (default 5000).
2012-08-12 03:58:08 [INFO] This process can take a while depending on the world's overall size. Also, depending on the chunk processing rate, players may experience lag for the duration.
2012-08-12 03:58:08 [INFO] You should now use wb trim confirm to start the process.
2012-08-12 03:58:08 [INFO] You can cancel at any time with wb trim cancel, or pause/unpause with wb trim pause.
2012-08-12 03:58:10 [INFO] WorldBorder map trimming task started.
2012-08-12 03:58:35 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 216 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (11.8% done)
2012-08-12 04:00:04 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 1016 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (25.5% done)
2012-08-12 04:01:55 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 1975 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (36.6% done)
2012-08-12 04:03:18 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 2718 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (45.2% done)
2012-08-12 04:03:58 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 3084 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (52.7% done)
2012-08-12 04:04:12 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 3203 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (61.1% done)
2012-08-12 04:05:07 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 3690 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (73.5% done)
2012-08-12 04:05:53 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] 0 entire region(s) and 4080 individual chunk(s) trimmed so far (100.0% done)
2012-08-12 04:05:53 [INFO] [WorldBorder] [Trim] task successfully completed!
```

Of course, the log doesn't only contain world border information, it also contains people's chats, as well as logs everything else that occurs. Therefore, I can't just tail the last 10 lines of the log and check that, as once 10 lines had passed (for example an error that prints more than 10 lines in the interval that the script waits before checking the last 10 lines), it's not going to ever going to be able to find anything that would cause it to realize that it finished, so it would wait forever, using up valuable resources and preventing the worlds from being trimmed until I noticed that something is wrong, which could take days, or even weeks to since it's automated.

Not only would it have to stop when it is completed, only for that world, but it will have to record the hour and minute when it started trimming the world, and only check after that, because if I trimmed the same world earlier it would cause problems otherwise, as there would already be the "task successfully completed" in the log for that world, which would cause the script to stop almost immediately. Does anyone see a solution to this? This makes my head hurt just thinking about it... :P

Comment: Dang, lost my answer on codereview while this got migrated.  Anyway, +1 for using a function as a condition.  However, you can safely drop the first instance of `is_running` in `main.`  Also, try this instead of is_running: `is_running() { screen -ls | grep "$SCREEN" > /dev/null; }`.  No need for `if/then` or `return 0|1`.  Just grep.   Time to prepare dinner.

Answer (score 1):

Would you find any advantage to using a '.lock' file while the script/function is running, and delete it on ANY kind of completion (error or otherwise)?

The lock file is a 0-byte (empty) file with a unique name (usually the same name as the filename, with '.lock' appended at the end). When your script is run, check for the existence of that file.  If it does not exist, create it (ie `touch $MCPATH.lock`) and then run your trim commands.

While that lock file *does* exist, simply `wait()` for a few seconds (or longer, as you wish) and then poll again.

Once the trim function completes (even if it completes with an error), delete that `.lock` file. Then simply handle the error (or success) as you would normally.

Comment: Problem is, this is a minecraft server, so all plugins are jar files running under the server process. The trim function isn't a normal bash command, it's a command running on the bukkit server console. It doesn't have a PID number, and it simply executes the command, (e.g. it just starts a child "process" in the bukkit server. I can't really call it a child process cause as it is a java plugin, it doesn't run independently of bukkit and therefore doesn't have it's own PID number.) Sorry if this explanation is confusing, if you need a better one, I'm sure I can think of something.

Comment: How does this prevent you from using a lock file? You don't need a PID for that. You can delete the lock file in your script after waiting 10 minutes for trim to complete; this would indeed prevent a new trimming to start within 10 minutes from the start of the previous one, but starting a new trimming immediately after the completion of the previous doesn't make much sense anyway, does it?